# RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match) not removing items

Tags: c#, monogame

Im making a game where we made a tilemap, the tilemap is a **list** with tile objects. Tile objects have a **position**. We want to be able to remove these tiles and asking around i go told to use

`tiles.RemoveAll(item => item.position == new Vector2(MathF.Round(playerPosition.X), MathF.Round(playerPosition.Y)))`

How ever, this does not remove any of the tile objects even if the vectors match.

Comment: It is likely that the vectors do not actually match, due to floating point precision.  Try checking for an approximate position instead.

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful to move inline calculations like `MathF.Round(playerPosition.X)` to a separate line (e.g., `var x = MathF.Round(playerPosition.X);`) and log it or inspect it in a debugger. It may not be what you expected.